# Verify my transformation matrices

Tags: linear-transformations

I came across this exercise:

> Let $\psi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear map with
>
> $$
> \psi\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}
> \quad\text{and}\quad
> \psi\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
> $$
>
> - For which bases is the transformation matrix obvious?
> - Determine the transformation matrix regarding the standard bases.

For the first task I have chosen bases
$$
B = \left(
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}
\right) \quad\text{and}\quad
C = \left(e_1, e_2, e_3\right)
$$
where $e_i$ are the unit vectors.

I have concluded that the transformation matrix is
$$
M^B_C (\psi) =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
-2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

For standard bases $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $T$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ I ended with this:
$$
M^S_T(\psi) =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 \\
-5 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I am unsure if I am right, so it would be good if someone could check my results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions are correct. You can easily check them yourself. Multiply $M_C^B(\psi)$ with $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\end{pmatrix}$ and with $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ (which is how $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\2\end{pmatrix}$ are represented with base $B$), and multiply $M_T^S(\psi)$ with $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\2\end{pmatrix}$.